# Git and SVN and branches

Tags: git, svn, production-environment, git-push, git-pull

I am new in git, I used to use svn at and now I am deploying my own website. I've got the follows

```
proyectos_git
  ->my_project.git
  ->my_project_bare_shared.git
mywebsite
  ->mywebsite_production  
  ->mywebsite_development
clone of ../proyectos_git/my_project.git and 
git remote add origin ../proyectos_git/my_project_bare_shared.git
```

I can do push and pull, but I don't know if my files are synchronizing. In svn when I do svn up I see what's happening with every file A for and added file, D for Deleted and G for a merge file after being updated.

What should I do to configurate well my enviroments?

Comment: `git pull` should report the changed files unless configured differently using with `merge.stat` property. 

On committing you see the set of changed/updated files as part of your commit message. So I don't understand exactly your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pushing you can:

```
git diff --name-status HEAD~
```

Before pushing:

```
git diff --name-status
```

After staging:

```
git diff --cached --name-status
```